# RInside with Qt, GTK+ or Tcl

Tags: qt, gtk, tcl, rinside

My question is: Do you know what toolkit between Qt, Gtk+ or Tcl/tk  is better  to develop an app with RInside?

I think I can do it with any of them, but I just find examples of RInside using Qt.

Can I use, for example, Gtk or Tcl/tk also?, and... What do you think is the best choice to make an efficient GUI  for a program in R?

Thanks

Comment: The best toolkit is the one you're comfortable with. It depends on what programming language you prefer - C++ (Qt), C (Gtk+) or Tcl (Tk). If they are equally good for you and you already found examples in Qt, then go for it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I refer that for example QT seems to be a little slow.I mean. I want to know your experience with the toolkits if you have one.

Comment: Tcl/Tk way slower than C++/Qt. I don't know how about GTK+, but it's in C, so I guess it's comparable with Qt.

Comment: The speed is usually not a problem; GUIs spend virtually all their time waiting for the user. That said, Tk's drawing and layout code is written in C: the scripted level handles events and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak for the Qt bindings which I have worked on, and which are documented via
the following:

- an entire [examples subdirectory](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/tree/master/inst/examples/qt) of the sources / installed package  devoted to this]
- blog posts about this several times which comes up [as the first Google hit for 'RInside Qt'](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25/); similarly for several of my presentations which featured this
- the entire chapter 9 in my [Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book)

You can probably work something out for Tcl/Tk and Gtk -- but given that RInside and Rcpp are C++ based, Qt seemed like a natural fit.

Comment: I think the asker means that she found *only* the Qt examples for RInside. I think their question really is: can I use RInside from other toolkits.

Comment: Ah, yes, I may have misread.

Comment: Yes!!  that is my main question, thanks Kuba Ober.  But, what do you think, are there other toolkits in that we can use RInside.  For example GTK+. I asked because I can't found documentation about that, just for QT.