# R and qt framework for GUIs: How can I use qt5 from within R?

Tags: r, qt, user-interface, qt5

Is there a way to use the up-to-date **qt5 framework** from within R code?

I have found the package "qtbase" for

> dynamic bindings to the Qt library for calling Qt methods and
>   extending Qt classes from R.

but it seems to support only qt4:

> SystemRequirements: Qt4 libraries and headers

Comment: qtbase is a part of this:http://qtinterfaces.r-forge.r-project.org/, it is unactive from 2009 and doesn't support qt5

Comment: @demonplus Wow - last change of the source code was five years ago: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/?root=qtinterfaces
Who is relying on this package? Or has the source code been migrated to github (or elsewhere) but nobody knows it?

Comment: It seems this project was not developed since then and there are no other projects. There is a mirror on github but it is also 5 years old https://github.com/rforge/qtinterfaces

Comment: You can still try to use this project with Qt 4.8 - it is still supported version

Comment: @demonplus I'm surprised to read that the package has been inactive since 2009 since the date of the [last version published on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qtbase/index.html) states July 17th, 2015.

Comment: The comments in the [`src` folder](https://github.com/ggobi/qtbase/tree/master/src) seem to suggest at least partial compatibility with Qt5.2.

Comment: @RHertel This is the last commit date and revision https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=qtinterfaces&revision=465

Comment: @demonplus Is this a different package, or has it been migrated? https://github.com/ggobi/qtbase/

Comment: @RHertel yes, it is a different package (a fork? of first one)

Comment: Look at reverse dependencies as a rough proxy of the usage of qtbase (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qtbase/index.html). You see there that only qtutils & qtpaint depends on qtbase, but these are complimentary functions to qtbase. There is also a suggest from ProgGUIinR, but this is a book about R GUIs. So, it seems no CRAN package actually uses QT for its GUI. Look at tcltk/tcltk2 and RGtk2, and you'll see more reverse dependencies. So Tk and Gtk2 are far more used by the CRAN R community. May be one reason for the lack of interest in its evolution to Qt5?

Comment: @PhilippeGrosjean Good points! I have also looked into RGtk2 but it has a similar problem: No support for Gtk3 (I will ask this in a separate question later). I don't like to end up with a GUI that must be migrated to a nother toolkit because it runs out of support. I think tcltk/tcltk2 is the only real option that has a stable support in R

Comment: Just for documentation purposes: I have found a note from Dirk Eddelbuettel on how to use QT(5) in C++ and execute R code via an embedded R via the R package **RInside**. This is the other way round as I wanted but is a possible option: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949725/rinside-with-qt-gtk-or-tcl